# Relation between full elliptic integrals of the first and third kind

Tags: special-functions, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I am working on a calculation involving the Ronkin function of a hyperplane in 3-space.
I get a horrible matrix with full elliptic integrals as entries. A priori I know that the matrix is symmetrical and that give me a relation between full elliptic integrals of the first and third kind.
I can not find transformations in the literature that explain the relation and I think I need one in order to simplify my matrix.

### The relation

With the notation

$\operatorname{K}(k) = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d\varphi}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\varphi}},$
$\qquad$ $\Pi(\alpha^2,k)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d\varphi}{(1-\alpha^2\sin^2\varphi)\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\varphi}}$

$k^2 = \frac{(1+a+b-c)(1+a-b+c)(1-a+b+c)(-1+a+b+c)}{16abc},\quad a,b,c > 0$

the following is true:

$2\frac{(1+a+b-c)(1-a-b+c)(a-b)}{(a-c)(b-c)}\operatorname{K}(k)+$

$(1-a-b+c)(1+a-b-c)\Pi\left( \frac{(1+a-b+c)(-1+a+b+c)}{4ac},k\right) +$

$\frac{(a+c)(1+b)(1-a-b+c)(-1-a+b+c)}{(a-c)(-1+b)}\Pi\left( \frac{(1+a-b+c)(-1+a+b+c)(a-c)^2}{4ac(1-b)^2},k\right)+$

$(1-a-b+c)(-1+a+b+c)\Pi\left( \frac{(1-a+b+c)(-1+a+b+c)}{4ac},k\right)+$

$\frac{(1+a)(b+c)(-1-a+b+c)(-1+a+b-c)}{(1-a)(c-b)}\Pi\left( \frac{(1-a+b+c)(-1+a+b+c)(b-c)^2}{4ac(1-a)^2},k\right)$

$==0$.

Is there some addition formula or transformation between elliptic integrals of the first and third kind that will explain this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [MGfun](http://algo.inria.fr/chyzak/mgfun.html) from Frédéric Chyzak?  It is a (Maple) package to deal with computations in multivariate Ore Algebras.  The main application of this is exactly the kind of problem you pose: finding relations between (multivariate) holonomic functions.  It is a generalization of WZ theory to the multi-variate case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that $a$, $b$, and $c$ have no relations among them?

I ask this because I attempted to (painstakingly!) copy your proposed equation over to *Mathematica* (taking care of the fact that the functions in it take the modulus $m=k^2$ as argument), and I keep getting complex results instead of 0.

On the other hand, your problem might actually be easier to solve if you use [Carlson's symmetric elliptic integrals](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19#PT3). Maybe you can try [re-expressing the Legendre forms as Carlson forms](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.25)?